# Decomposing S gate in two T gate with qiskit

Tags: qiskit, transpile

Let's suppose I define a basis gate set and the following circuit.

```
import qiskit as qk
from qiskit import QuantumRegister, ClassicalRegister, QuantumCircuit,Aer
backend = Aer.get_backend('unitary_simulator')

basis_gates=['h',"cx",'t']
qreg_q = QuantumRegister(1, 'q')
circuit = QuantumCircuit(qreg_q)
circuit.s(0)
qk.transpile(QT.circuit, backend, basis_gates)
```

I get the TranspilerError
`TranspilerError: "Unable to map source basis {('s', 1)} to target basis {'measure', 'h', 'delay', 'snapshot', 'cx', 'barrier', 't', 'reset'} over library <qiskit.circuit.equivalence.EquivalenceLibrary object at 0x14aefb3a1160>."`

Why doesn't `transpile` work, being S gate = TT? It should be able to decompose it, right?

Comment: I tried different universal sets and I was never able to decompose $S=T^2$, but maybe there is one that allows it.

Comment: If one looks at the unitary, they are the same, so it should not depend on the other gates in the set, as long as T is in the set, right?

Answer (score 2):

The `transpile` doesn't work because the identity $S = TT$ is not there in the `SessionEquivalenceLibrary`. You can add an entry manually like this, and your circuit will be transpiled:

```
from qiskit.circuit.equivalence_library import SessionEquivalenceLibrary as sel
from qiskit.circuit.library import SGate
qc_eq = QuantumCircuit(1)
qc_eq.t(0)
qc_eq.t(0)
s = SGate()
sel.add_equivalence(s, qc_eq)
```

I assume the identity is not available by default, because it is not essential. Similarly, you won't be able to transpile an $X$ gate in terms of $H$ and $Z$, unless you add an identity $X = HZH$ explicitly to `SessionEquivalenceLibrary`.